# Why implicitly declared variable don't show up in autocomplete?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property uniqueAccounts() As Dictionary(Of String, ExchangesClass)
Private Shared Sub setUniqueAccounts()
    Dim lines = _accounts11
    Dim dictAccount = New Dictionary(Of String, ExchangesClass)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim exchange = line._Exchange
        If Not dictAccount.ContainsKey(exchange) Then
            dictAccount(exchange) = line
        End If
    Next
    _uniqueAccounts = dictAccount
End Sub
```

Here,_uniqueAccounts is implicitly declared

So I type _unique

I get this

[image]

Why it didn't show up?

The variable _uniqueAccounts truly exist. I don't get compiler warning when using it. Why it didn't show up?

Comment: Works fine for me using vs2019. Posibly a bug with your version.

Comment: The fact that field is filtered out of the Intellisense list should not be surprising. The intent of auto-implemented properties is that you should never need to access the backing field directly.  The fact that the compiler generated field name is a valid VB variable name that can be manually entered could be viewed as either an oversight or laziness on the implementer's part; they could just as easily given the field a name that is invalid according to VB variable naming rules similar to the way C# does.

Comment: It's a read only property. That means someone has to set the value and the only way to set the value will be to access the _uniqueAccounts directly. Also, @DavidWilson says that it works fine for him

Comment: I downloaded 2019 and I still don't see it. Intellisense still don't work. I disagree with @TnTinMn too. That's because you obviously have to access the private field for a read only public property

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that maybe there was something changed in your intellisense settings that has been carried over to your new installation of vs2019

Comment: "you obviously have to access the private field for a read only public property" - you do realize that you can always use the _long form_ property syntax, right?  Also, [Auto-Implemented Properties-Backing Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties#backing-field) specifically states "the backing field does not show in an IntelliSense word completion list".

Comment: @TnTinMn that comment should be an answer. Yes I realized I can use the long form. I don't want it